# Dimension of basis for a plane?

Tags: linear-algebra

$\mathbb{R}^3$ over $\mathbb{R}$ has dimension 3.

However, if we have a plane $\Pi$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, its basis will only have 2 elements and so it has dimension 2 over $\mathbb{R}$?

I am finding this difference a bit difficult to understand conceptually. Any help/comments would be appreciated.

Comment: The idea of dimension is intrinsic to the object and doesn't depend on any ambient space it lives in.  A plane in $\mathbb{R}^2$, $\mathbb{R}^3$, or even $\mathbb{R}^4$ will have dimension two.

Comment: Building on Matthews comment, this can be even thought further. If there are only two independent direction in which you can move, then the space is considered to be two dimensional. E.g. a sphere surface like the surface of the earth is 2-dimensional even though it needs three dimensions to embed. On the surface of the earth you have only two independent direction to move along (longitute and latitute).

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense now :)